# After posting JSON to external System, I need to return back to salesforce /apex/response page which is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, html, post

```
<apex:page standardController="Rfleet_Car_Set__c" showHeader="true" extensions="csbreceiver" action="{!test}">
<html>
<object style="height : 1200px;width : 1300px;overflow:hidden;">    
    <form name="frm" action="{!$Setup.Rfleet_CSB__c.Rfleet_CSB_URL__c}method="POST">
    <input type="Hidden" name="retURL" id="JSON4" value="https://rfleet--rfleetfull--c.cs83.visual.force.com/apex/csbresponse"/>
         <input type="Hidden" name="csb_username" id="JSON1" value="{!$Setup.Rfleet_CSB__c.Rfleet_CSB_UserId__c}"/>
         <input type="Hidden" name="csb_password" id="JSON2" value="{!$Setup.Rfleet_CSB__c.Rfleet_CSB_Password__c}"/>    
         <input type="Hidden" name="config" id="JSON3"  />        

         <!--value="{!Rfleet_Car_Set__c.Rfleet_CSB_JSON_String__c}"/>-->

    </form>
    </object>
    <script>
        var strJSON = [];
        <apex:repeat value="{!str2}" var="thing">
        strJSON .push('{!JSENCODE(thing)}');        
        </apex:repeat> 
        document.frm.config.value=strJSON;
        document.forms["frm"].submit();
    </script>
</html>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: So you are successful in sending the info from the VF page (which you provided) but are having trouble sending / receiving info back (Which you have provided no context for). It will be difficult to answer the question when you post the working part but no real information on the part that is not working.

Comment: Eric:  I have posted my whole code,  could you please  have a look.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes!!!! Got the solution...In CSBReturnJson page, I passed the return URL in the form action and
>   it works. below is how I passed the return url and with record ID.

```
<apex:page standardController="Rfleet_Car_Set__c" showHeader="true" extensions="csbreceiver" action="{!test}">
<html>
<object style="height : 1200px;width : 1300px;overflow:hidden;">    
    <form name="frm" action="{!$Setup.Rfleet_CSB__c.Rfleet_CSB_URL__c}returnUrl=https://rfleet--rfleetfull--c.cs83.visual.force.com/apex/csbresponse?id={!Rfleet_Car_Set__c.id}" method="POST">   
         <input type="Hidden" name="csb_username" id="JSON1" value="{!$Setup.Rfleet_CSB__c.Rfleet_CSB_UserId__c}"/>
         <input type="Hidden" name="csb_password" id="JSON2" value="{!$Setup.Rfleet_CSB__c.Rfleet_CSB_Password__c}"/>    
         <input type="Hidden" name="config" id="JSON3"  />        

         <!--value="{!Rfleet_Car_Set__c.Rfleet_CSB_JSON_String__c}"/>-->

    </form>
    </object>
    <script>
        var strJSON = [];
        <apex:repeat value="{!str2}" var="thing">
        strJSON .push('{!JSENCODE(thing)}');        
        </apex:repeat> 
        document.frm.config.value=strJSON;
        document.forms["frm"].submit();
    </script>
</html>

</apex:page>
```